# Missreading Mongodb Data

Tags: python, mongodb

It worked in the first try but not after doing some modifications in the database

E2C Doc

```
 {'_id': ObjectId('65267b47b2396ab97ef1dc10'), 'Client__r.Name': 'Total', 'Module__r.Name': 'Oil','Module__r.Reference_Offre__c': 'O-AMP-CBA'}
 {'_id': ObjectId('65267b47b2396ab97ef1dc11'), 'Client__r.Name': 'Shell', 'Module__r.Name': 'Gaz','Module__r.Reference_Offre__c': 'O-AMP-CAR'}
```

IF Doc

```
{'Id Impact': 'a0b1r00000P0LOxAAN',
 'Module__r.Domain__r.Name': 'Heavy',
 'Module__r.Name': 'Oil',
  '_id': ObjectId('65267b74b2396ab97ef1ddbb')}
 {'Id Impact': 'a0b1r00000P0LOyAAN',
  'Module__r.Domain__r.Name': 'Light',
  'Module__r.Name': 'Gaz',
  '_id': ObjectId('65267b74b2396ab97ef1ddbc')}
 {'Id Impact': 'a0b1r00000P0LOzAAN',
  'Module__r.Domain__r.Name': 'Heavy',
  'Module__r.Name': 'Gaz',
  '_id': ObjectId('65267b74b2396ab97ef1ddbd')}......
```

when i read the documents it gives me the actual data but when I try too see what a client possees i get no results and in some codes tells me the client doesn't exist :

```
  def get_modules_and_domains_for_client(client_name):    
     client_info = db["E2C"].find_one({"Client__r.Name": client_name})  

if client_info:      
    modules = client_info.get("Modules", [])  

    result = []
    for module_name in modules:
        module_details = db["IF"].find_one({"Module__r.Name": module_name})
        if module_details:
            domain_name = module_details.get("Domain__r.Name", "")
            result.append({"Module__r.Name": module_name, "Domain__r.Name": domain_name})

    return result
else:
    return []

 client_name = "Total"  
modules_and_domains = get_modules_and_domains_for_client(client_name)  
print(modules_and_domains)
```

I get [] as a result

it should give me this
Modules possessed by the client Total: Oil, Gaz
in client shell's case this: Gaz

Answer (score 0):

This question was pretty difficult to troubleshoot since it lacks a bunch of relevant information that is required for doing so. But in the process of standing up a playground to demonstrate the missing information I think I've incidentally stumbled upon the problem. My suspicion is that the problem lies in the very first sentence of the question:

> It worked in the first try but *not after doing some modifications in the database*

What, specifically, were those changes? (This is an example of the type of additional information that's incredibly helpful for troubleshooting, *especially* when the system worked fine before the changes).

My guess is that you've renamed the fields in the documents, is that correct? Perhaps moving from something like `Module__r_Name` to the current `Module__r.Name` structure?

The reason this is problematic is because there is ambiguity when dots (`.`) appear in field names in MongoDB's query language. *Typically* dots represent levels of embedding. So instead of the current structure that looks like this:

```
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("65267b47b2396ab97ef1dc10"),
      "Client__r": "Total",
      "Module__r.Name": "Oil",
      "Module__r.Reference_Offre__c": "O-AMP-CBA"
    }
```

The document could have alternatively been structured as this:

```
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("65267b47b2396ab97ef1dc10"),
      "Client__r": "Total",
      "Module__r": {
          "Name": "Oil",
          "Reference_Offre__c": "O-AMP-CBA"
      }
    }
```

And the problem is that, by default, querying on `"Module__r.Name"` matches the second document *but not the first one*. See that here in [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/s7ZlBDFbdr4).

While technically you can workaround this by using things like `$getField`, I would discourage you from continuing down this path. Even a simple query becomes more convoluted (see [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IEVrUqG8lvB)) and you will continue to encounter weird problems going forward that will slow you down. Instead I would suggest either:

1. Removing the dots from the field name (keeping the flat structure), e.g. replace them with a different character.
2. Use an embedded structure like shown above (which also removes the dots from the field names themselves, they will just be [used when querying](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#query-on-nested-field-with-dot-notation)).

You can see an example of the latter approach below.

---

As a bonus recommendation, everything you're doing here in code can be done in a single aggregation call to the database. Something along the lines of the following:

```
db.E2C.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "Client__r.Name": "Shell"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "IF",
      "localField": "Module__r.Name",
      "foreignField": "Module__r.Name",
      "as": "IF"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      Client: "$Client__r.Name",
      "Modules Processed": {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$IF.Module__r.Name",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            "$setUnion": [
              "$$value",
              [
                "$$this"
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

For the (structurally modified) sample data provide, this aggregation yields the following output:

```
[
  {
    "Client": "Shell",
    "Modules Processed": [
      "Gaz"
    ]
  }
]
```

See how it works in [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ny-0kF-NVRp)